# How to interpret a vertical line at the end of something?

Tags: calculus

For example:

[image]

The last three lines have a |t=ti, what does that mean?

Comment: "evaluated at the point $t=t_{i}$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is defined by
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) \Big|_{x=a}^b & := f(b) - f(a)\\
f(x) \Big|_{x=a} & := f(a)
\end{align*}$$
(note the "inconsistency" in the sign of $f(a)$)
The notation allows for notational improvements of statements like
$$\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi(x,s) \right|_{x=x_0}$$
Wich says first compute the partial derivative of $\phi$ w.r.t. $x$ and then "plug in" $x_0$ for $x$. Compare this to
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi(x_0,s) = 0$$
Because there is no free variable $x$ in the argument list of $\phi$.
Another problem can occur with the total derivative:
$$\phi_x(x,y(x),z_0(x)) + y'(x) \phi_y(x,y(x),z_0(x)) = \\
\left. \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \phi(x, y(x), z) \right|_{z=z_0(x)} \ne \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \phi(x,y(x),z_0(x)) \\
 = \phi_x(x,y(x),z_0(x)) + y'(x) \phi_y(x,y(x), z_0(x)) + z_0'(x) \phi_z(x,y(x),z_0(x))$$
because the chain rules to be applied are different.

Answer (score 1):

The $\mid_{t=t_i}$ means evaluate the stuff before with $t_i$ substituted for $t$.